# Download of values to web page doesn't working properly

Tags: regex, vb.net

Until recently, everything worked, then the website has had the great idea to up the font and therefore part of my program doesn't work now. But let's get to the gist of the problem, I use a code to download the values of a table football scores that are constantly updated.
The code works fine, the only bug currently is in the way the value is captured by my regex.

Especially if the team has a table name like: "Manchester" then the values are downloaded properly, and if it is abbreviated from the site as: "Manchester Uni ...." then the bug appears.

I capture the team name using this code:

```
.Name = Remove_Tags(Regex.Match(Content, "<td class=""text team large-link"">(.+?)</td>").Groups(1).ToString)
```

**Site link example:**
 itDOTsoccerwayDOTcom

**Image Example:** 
http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/d022/ho877h9ahbo6bffzg.jpg
**Complete class project**:
 http://pastebin.com/kGxCXyWQ

to be precise, my code works on the table "Classifica" because the name "Manchester United" is full, while on other tables as "Tabelle larghe" values are not captured as the team's name is abbreviated from the site. I ask for help to you to fix this bug, my clients complain to me and I have to find an efficient solution as soon as possible. Sorry if I haven't insert the image here but I doesn't have the necessary reputation.